# One of Due Days and Day of Month Due must be specified to indicate the Term Type

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm using the ipp devkit 2.0 for .Net and am trying to add a new Sales Term called Due on Receipt. This sales term has a Due Date of 0. If I go to QB Online and use the UI to add a Due On Receipt with a 0 Due Days, it works fine. However, when I try to add it using the devkit I keep getting the error

"Error validating Sales Term Type:One of Due Days and Day of Month Due must be specified to indicate the Term Type."

How do I create a term called Due on Receipt?

The code I use is below:

```
qboSalesTerm.ItemsElementName = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType3[]
                {
                    Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType3.DueDays,
                    Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType3.DiscountDays,
                    Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemsChoiceType3.DiscountPercent
                };
        qboSalesTerm.Items = new object[]
                {
                    DueDays,
                    DiscountDays,
                    DiscountPercent
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting 0 DueDays, you should be setting that variable.

However, it looks like there is a bug in QBO IDS V2 that won't allow you to have DueDays set to 0.

I have submitted a bug against this - QBO-10473.

Once you do get this set, you should be getting back the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FaultInfo xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd">
    <Message>Error validating Due Days:Invalid integer.
</Message>
    <ErrorCode>TERM_REQUEST_BAD</ErrorCode>
    <Cause>TERM_INVALID_DUE_DAYS</Cause>
</FaultInfo>
```